# Getting xpath or CSS for element of Body within iframe tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Given the following html markup structure:

```
<body>
  <div id=Body>
   <div>
    <iframe>//Data within iframe is generated dynamically
     <html>
      <head></head>
       <body>
        <div id="abcdef">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </body>
     </html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
 <body>
```

I want to access the xpath and CSS Selector for `<div id="abcdef">` but I am not able to, as it is referring to the internal `<html>` tag as different frame.

Comment: That's not how code should be formatted on this site - please remove all those unnecessary backticks and indent code by four spaces. Then, _show_ what you would like to find in this document.

Comment: Edited to clean up the code formatting, but left the mismatched closing tags; unsure whether it reflects typo or bad HTML

Comment: I am trying it since yesterday to enter the code part but it wasn't accepting. So finally used backticks and indent code and it is accepted. Is it ok now.

Comment: @Praj you just need to enter your code as it is and select your code and click on code sample.

Comment: @Praj it would also help to see what xpath's you have attempted... but as the others have so un-eloquently said, you need properly formatted html/xml. Without properly formatted html, no xpath selectors will work.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
<body>
    <div id="Body">
    <iframe>//Data within iframe is generated dynamically
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div id="abcdef">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was able to successfully select that element with:

```
//iframe//div[@id = 'abcdef']
```

Try it out here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

However, this is not going to work in the DOM, because of iframe security restrictions. This xpath is correct, but you can test in the chrome dev console with

```
$x("//iframe//div[@id = 'abcdef']")
```

and see that you do not get any results. When dealing with HTML documents, your browsers are going to restrict your access to iframes, so you will need to actually grab the iframe, read the html, and then search that html. You will not be able to use an xpath or css selector, as far as I am aware, without getting the content of the iframe and then searching through it as it's own document/element.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the iframe like below worked,

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('frameid'));

To refer more methods, 
Here's [a link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/test/selenium/webdriver/common/frame_switching_tests.py)

Switching to frame, enables you to access all the elements directly.

for above example xpath will be:
//*[@id='abcdef']